# ManyToOne HashCode & Equal implementation

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities like this :

**1.Project :**

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id", unique=true )
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="project", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>();

//Getters & Setters
```

}

**2.User :**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Collaborator> collaborators = new HashSet<>(); 

//Getters & Setters
}
```

**3.Collaborator :**

```
@Entity
public class Collaborator implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "ProjectID" , nullable = true)
private Project project;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "UserID", nullable = true)
private User user;

//Getters & Setters
}
```

How should hashCode & equals needs to be implemented ?

Cause when I generate them automatically with Eclipse I get a `StackOverFlow Error` And it's a never ending loop.

Any suggestion would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: quick guess, when you generate them, they will do a equals, on project, which contains Collaborators, which then would call back to the Project, think which values you want in the when testing for equality

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should implement your `equals` and `hashcode` using "Business key equality"

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html

In your case, you should only use the field `id`.

You may select this field when Eclipse is generating the `hashcode` and `equals` methods.

Comment: You mean hashCode will be like this : `@Override
 public int hashCode() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  
  result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
  return result;
 }`

Comment: I think you can even simplify by having `return  ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode()`

Comment: Read more carefully your link !! Identifier MUST NOT be used when generated. A generated id is definitely not a business key.

Answer (score -1):

At first, sorry for my poor english, but i believe that your mistake is put all fields in methods equals and hashCode. You must put only "plain" fields, not Lists and Sets.

Please, try to do this and after answer if solved this problem.